# How to plot a square root with "negative part"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I cant get the function

```
\$sqrt[2]{x+2}+1\$
```

plotted since it has a negative part and the system ,rightfully, does not plot it.

I was expecting something like
[image]
but cant be plotted, I have been trying to rotate, or express like  a fraction power but it is not working.
All that it gets is
[image]

But even so, the center seems to be out of scope.
The code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis equal,
            samples = 200,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
            ]
            \addplot[red]{sqrt{x+2}+1} node[pos=1,below]{$ $};
            \addplot[red]{-1*(sqrt{x+2}+1)} node[pos=1,below]{$ $};
            \draw[fill=blue] (-2,1) circle (0.2);
            \draw[dashed,color=blue] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:-2,1);

            \fill[fill=yellow,opacity=0.5](0,1)--(0.2,1)--(0.2,4)--(0.2,4)--(0,4);  
            \fill[fill=pink,opacity=0.5](-2,0)--(-2,0.2)--(4,0.2)--(4,0)--(4,0);    

            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}       
            \end{flushleft}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax for sqrt is false: you are using braces instead of parentheses.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis equal,
            samples = 200,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
            ]
            \addplot[red]{sqrt(x+2)+1} node[pos=1,below]{$ $};
            \addplot[red]{-1*(sqrt(x+2)+1)} node[pos=1,below]{$ $};
            \draw[fill=blue] (-2,1) circle (0.2);
            \draw[dashed,color=blue] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:-2,1);

            \fill[fill=yellow,opacity=0.5](0,1)--(0.2,1)--(0.2,4)--(0.2,4)--(0,4);
            \fill[fill=pink,opacity=0.5](-2,0)--(-2,0.2)--(4,0.2)--(4,0)--(4,0);

            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]